# Repairing Win 7 boot partition unsuccessful in dual-boot laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

A few years ago I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Win 7 laptop using a program called "Wubi." After rebooting, I selected Ubuntu from the menu list and Ubuntu ran just fine. Later, when I tried to reboot back into Win 7 the Win 7 menu entry would quickly flash, disappear, and my screen would go dark and idle. I searched for a solution online and found that many Win 7 users had run the Wubi installer from their Win 7 desktops, and had the same problem that I did; that possibly the version of Wubi I had may have been defective because of a bad GRUB.

I could still access my Win 7 files from within Ubuntu so I didn't worry, but 
I searched and researched online for possible solutions on "guru" websites, and tried a few of them with either the Win 7 CD or the Ubuntu CD; EasyBCD, Gparted, DOS command line fixes--none of the methods worked, so I decided to leave the Windows partition alone, hoping that one day I'd have collected enough savvy (and was brave enough) to try again.

I made three attempts today with no success using Ubuntu's Boot Repair app: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS works just fine, Win 7 still won't boot, despite being told onscreen that the Win Bootloader was repaired.

So, if anyone has had/knows of a situation similar to mine, and can offer some insight in helping me to solve it, I'd appreciate your feedback on this. I've included the url that was generated on my last attempt this afternoon:

http://paste2.org/gINsE57m

I'm certain that this issue can be fixed--I just don't have the knowledge and skill to fix it.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

spawnKRON

P.S. I haven't posted here in quite a while, so please forgive me if I've unwittingly used improper etiquette.

Comment: Mathilde, I have tried to install bootmgr and bootmbr from windows 7 repair;  no success, I'm afraid. Ubuntu Boot Repair suggested that I try installing the boot menu on sda5 Ext4, but I'd rather get more information from here before attempting it

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot really be fixed from Ubuntu which makes it kind of off topic here. I believe you'll have better chances of getting a good answer on [SU].